"javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch while decrypting data using AES/GCM/NoPadding in springboot
I'm encountering an issue while working on encryption and decryption in my Java project using the AES/GCM/NoPadding algorithm. When decrypting the data, I get the following exception:
Exception Occurred javax.crypto.AEADBadTagException: Tag mismatch!nat
java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode$GCMDecrypt.doFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:1395)nat
java.base/com.sun.crypto.provider.GaloisCounterMode.engineDoFinal(GaloisCounterMode.java:406)nat
java.base/javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:2205)nat cmi.util.CMIUtil.decrypt(CMIUtil.java:802)nat
cmi.util.AnalyticsUtil.getBUUserCookieInformation(AnalyticsUtil.java:82)nat
cmi.util.RequestEncodeFilter.sessionServer(RequestEncodeFilter.java:143)nat
cmi.util.RequestEncodeFilter.doFilter(RequestEncodeFilter.java:57)nat
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)nat
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)nat
org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)nat
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)nat
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)nat
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)nat
org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)nat
org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)nat 
org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189

Here are the encrpt and decrpt functions i am using in the code
  public static String decrypt(String encrypted) {
    try {
        log.info("In decrypt: "+ encrypted);
      String strPassword = "";
      SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strPassword.getBytes(), "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
      GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, strPassword.getBytes());
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, spec);
      byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));
      return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred", ex);
    }
    return null;
  }

  public static String encrypt(String value) {
      log.info("In encrypt: "+ value);
    try {
      String strPassword = "";
      SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(strPassword.getBytes(), "AES");
      Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
      GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(128, strPassword.getBytes());
      cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, spec);
      byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
      return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        log.error("Exception Occurred", ex);
    }
    return null;
  }

Additional Information
Java version: Java 11]
The encrypted data is passed as a Base64-encoded string.

The key is missing. AES requires a 16, 24 or 32 bytes key. If such a key is specified, the code works, s. online here https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/1ycL. Beyond that, I can't find any problem that could cause such an exception. Presumably your data is inconsistent. Post sample data so that the problem is reproducible.

Note that your code has vulnerabilities, especially the use of the key as IV, which is a serious flaw for GCM (s. here). Other problems are the direct use of a password as key and the missing specification of the charset encoding in getBytes() and new String() (for Java versions below 18).
